# json.dump not writing to file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, file-io

I used the `dump` function like this with a file called test.py:

```
import json

li = [2, 5]
test = open('test.json', 'w')
json.dump(li, test)
```

But it didn't write to the JSON file after the code ran.
Why is this? What is the correct way to use `json.dump`?

Comment: What is the content of `test.json` after running the code? How did you run the code?

Comment: It may be writing to a different directory than you think. Add `import os; print(os.getcwd())` to see where it goes.

Comment: AFAIK files are closed automatically when Python exits. I suspect not explicitly closing the file is not the problem here (assuming the code is executed as a script).

Comment: @mkrieger1 - true... usually. if you are running a script in cpython, objects at script level are deleted - and for a file, that includes flush and close. But a shell or something like a jupyter notebook, or a non-C based python may behave differently. If what we see is a script run at the command line, the file should flush and close. Otherwise, poster should let us know the exeuction environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Changes are usually written to disk in blocks, usually on the order of 2 or 4KiB or so. Since your test file is tiny, the changes are not flushed from the REPL until you close the file, or the REPL or your script terminates.

Files have a `close` method you can use to close explicitly. However, the idiomatic way to work with files in python is using a `with` block:

```
import json

li = [2, 5]
with open('test.json', 'w') as test:
    json.dump(li, test)
```

This is roughly, equivalent to

```
li = [2, 5]
test = open('test.json', 'w')
try:
    json.dump(li, test)
finally:
    test.close()
```

Comment: So you're saying, I forgot to close the file and the file didn't change because of buffering or something? Also, thx btw

Comment: @user14354511. Basically yes. Reading and writing to disk is very slow, so most of the time, the OS will buffer your data in memory in blocks, and write them as they become available. Same for reads: you ask for 5 bytes, but it will read the entire 4K block in so when you ask for the next 5, it doesn't have to read again. Flushing is the act of forcing a write through of your data. You can flush manually, or just close the file, since that flushes as part of the operation. Also, you can open files without buffering, not that's only if you really know what you're doing.

Comment: @user14354511. You can do the following: open a file, write to it. Nothing will happen. Dump 4k or so of gibberish it zeros, and you'll see something on disk, even before you close the file. When you close the file, it will get a little bit bigger.

Comment: Ok, thank you! :)